# SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio : configure autocomplete in intellisense

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have a database with some tables which begin like SQL commands, for example:

- `COUNTries`
- `TOPics`

And so on. I would like to configure intellisense in a way, so it does not autocomplete 
when I write `cou...` into countries but into count for example.

How can I configure that?